# Meaning of Purple Dashed Line without Arrow in Doxygen Collaboration Diagram for Groups?

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup, collaboration-diagram

When creating a Collaboration Diagram in Doxygen that specifies the connections between [Doxygen groups](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html), what is the meaning of a purple dashed line without an arrow?

This option does not exist in the Doxygen documentation, the most similar option is a purple dashed line with an arrow, which is according to Doxygen documentation:

> A purple dashed **arrow** indicated a "usage" relation, the edge of the arrow is labeled with the variable(s) responsible for the relation. Class A uses class B, if class A has a member variable m of type C, where B is a subtype of C (e.g. C could be B, B, T).

The documentation: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html

I've created a Doxygen Collaboration Diagram by adding the argument `GENERATE_HTML = YES`. Also important to note that my code contains [Doxygen groups](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html). Here is the diagram I received:

Doxygen Collaboration graph with purple dashed line

[image: Doxygen Collaboration graph with purple dashed line]

The diagram describes the relations between the Doxygen groups I created. It contains a purple dashed line without an arrow, this option does not exist in the Doxygen documentation.

So the question is - what does it mean when there's no arrow in the purple dashed line? Is it the same but without a usage direction?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a bit long for a comment.
When looking at the grouping doxygen example and doing some standalone tests (and setting `HAVE_DOT=YES`) we see in the code:

```
/** @ingroup group1 group2 group3 group4
 *  namespace N1 is in four groups
 *  @sa @link group1 The first group@endlink, group2, group3, group4
 *
 *  Also see @ref mypage2
 */
namespace N1 {};
```

and in the documentation of the `\ingroup` command:

> If the `\ingroup` command is placed in a comment block of a compound entity (like class, file or namespace), then it will be added to the group(s) identified by the `<groupname>`(s).

In other words the `namespace N1` is part of the the different groups and this is a sort of usage relation between the different groups "through" the `namespace N1`

Comment: Yes, in the case of my diagram the dashed purple line represents a namespace both groups use. The questions is still if the exact definition of this line is "modules that have a common namespace", or maybe it appears in more cases (or less)?

Comment: For a class it is a dotted "orange" / "yellowish" line.

Comment: Quick look in the code gave (for what it is worth):     member: "darkorchid3",
    class: "orange",
    namespace: "blueviolet",
    file: "darkgreen",
    page: "firebrick4",
    directory: "grey75"